# can someone explain the following homebrew install command?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

What does the "$" sign mean in following command?
    `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Comment: download and execute the code written on that link in ruby

Comment: ruby evaluates the output of the curl command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shell feature called [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution). `$(command)` is replaced by the command's output:

```
$ echo puts 1 + 2
puts 1 + 2

$ ruby -e "$(echo puts 1 + 2)"
3
```

The second line is equivalent to `ruby -e "puts 1 + 2"`.

In your example, the `curl` command downloads and ouputs the [Ruby file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install) and `ruby -e` evaluates it.